# How to keep footer from moving out of the way of elements above when the window gets height decreases

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to get my footer to stop moving out of the way of other elements with the height of the browser decreases. Instead I'd just like it to stay put and be able to scroll down.

Here is a link to the page it is happening on:

http://fine-grain-2.myshopify.com/cart

Here is the CSS for my footer:

```
footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 1em;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is an example of what is happening:

GOOD

[image]

BAD
[image]

I've tried everything I know and looked at other websites with firebug that are doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try clear:both?

Comment: Nope, holy crap I've been coding too long today. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add the following css:

```
clear:both;
```

Comment: Hey thanks. Now how would I get it to stop pushing into the elements above?

Comment: Could you put a link to your site, create a jsfiddle or post your code?

Comment: Well, I see you have no padding or margin on the top of your footer. What is the html structure and the css for the content above it? Good to know since the question is about how they are interacting.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the HTML and CSS but if you add  `clear:both; width:100%;` to the footer it looks as though it will solve your issue from the screenshots.